# Separate String at Chr(10)

Tags: vba, excel

**Description:** I have a String that is created in a loop:

```
PString = PString & Chr(10) & ActiveCell.Offset(i - 2, 0).Value
```

During the marco I have to separate the strings again at the point Chr(10)

**Problem:**
I dont know how to search for Chr(10) in the string and separate the string at that point. I tried

```
For each PChar in PString
If PChar = Chr(10) then
...
next
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> search for Chr(10) in the string and separate the string at that point.

You can use a variant array and use `SPLIT()` with `Chr(10)` as a delimiter.

```
Dim MyAr
Dim PString As String, i As Long

PString = PString & Chr(10) & ActiveCell.Offset(i - 2, 0).Value
PString = PString & Chr(10) & ActiveCell.Offset(i - 3, 0).Value

MyAr = Split(PString, Chr(10))

For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
    Debug.Print MyAr(i)
Next
```